# JavaScript parseInt conversion is buggy

Tags: javascript

When running

```js
   console.log(parseInt("9658921879781125"))
```

it gives a value of `9658921879781124`, which is less than the original value.

Why is this the case?

Comment: http://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html

Comment: but it is able to convert 9658921879781126 properly

Comment: See G. Petrioli's answer. It's unsafe, it doesn't mean it will fail every time.

Comment: Yea I am now taking a substring of the biginteger and comparing it so that it would be less that the safe limit. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be because

```
9658921879781125 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER // true
```

So it is unsafe to try to work with numbers greater than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

---

> The `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant has a value of `9007199254740991` (9,007,199,254,740,991 or ~9 quadrillion). The reasoning behind that number is that JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point format numbers as specified in IEEE 754 and can only safely represent numbers between -(2<sup>53</sup> - 1) and 2<sup>53</sup> - 1.
>
> **Safe in this context refers to the ability to represent integers exactly and to correctly compare them**.